# How to send and receive messages through a PHP socket in the same program

Tags: php, php-socket

I have written a simple socket program to send a message from client to server. That works fine and I need to get a response from  the server to client.
Can I do it in a same socket program?If yes how can I do it?

Here is my code for the server socket.

```
<?php
$address="127.0.0.1";
$port="3222";
$sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("Cannot create a socket");
socket_bind($sock,$address,$port) or die("Couldnot bind to socket");
socket_listen($sock) or die("Couldnot listen to socket");
$accept=socket_accept($sock) or die("Couldnot accept");
$read=socket_read($accept,1024) or die("Cannot read from socket");
echo $read;
```

?>

Here is the code for Client socket.

```
<?php
$address="127.0.0.1";
$port="3222";
$msg="Hello server";

$sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("Cannot create a socket");
socket_connect($sock,$address,$port) or die("Could not connect to the socket");
socket_write($sock,$msg);
```

?>

Can somebody help me please....

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call `socket_read()` after writing to a socket to wait for an answer.

Comment: But I need to create a user interface to send and receive messages through input textboxes.Is there any possible way to do it? I have tried it, but the client waits for the user input from the server and fails to run the program.

Comment: You will need AJAX to achieve this. Have a look at some PHPChat software...there are quite a few of them out there. Will take way to long to explain all the details here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418814/Socket-Programming-in-PHP) which works for me